# GRUB IS GONE - WINDOWS 10 / UBUNTU DUAL OS

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

I am trying to setup my PC with Windows 10 and Ubuntu (minimal installation option) on different partitions.

I started off by wiping the disk completely and installing Windows 10, which was succesful.

After this, I reorganized the partitions and installed Ubuntu from a bootable USB (Windows and Ubuntu on separate partitions)

Current partition organization is then:

- WIN: the Windows OS partition
- UBU: the Ubuntu OS partition
- DAT: the personal data partition
- some other smaller partitions wherefrom I do not know the origin.

After the installation is completed, GRUB does not appear and my PC boots straight into Windows 10. However I can get into Ubuntu from Windows' Advanced Startup option (reboot from 'ubuntu device').

What I want to achieve best-case would be: GRUB showing on startup with the option to choose between booting into Ubuntu (as a primary option) or booting into Windows 10 (as a secondary option). Also both OS's installed on a different partition would be preferable.

I have already tried to fix this issue by using the boot-repair tool and by changing the boot order (which was initially set correctly in my opinion) with efibootmgr. But none of those attempts were succesful.

The result from the efibootmgr was:

```
sudo efibootmgr

BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0000,2003,2001,2002
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0001* UEFI: Network Card 
Boot0002* UEFI: Network Card 
Boot0003* ubuntu
Boot0004* UEFI: Network Card 
Boot0005* UEFI: Network Card 
Boot2001* EFI USB Device
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM
Boot2003* EFI Network
```

Should I change the installation order (first Ubuntu, then Windows)?

Should I give up and install them with the 'alongside each other' option?

Help with this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You cannot install multiple OS into the same partition. You can try, but it won't end well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: Hi, since I'm very new to this subject and due to the fact that I have already managed to install both OS's I will need more information than what is in the link that you provided. Unless it would be sufficient to run the commands in step 13?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After disabling Fast Boot, disabling Secure Boot and doing a bcdedit inside Windows (as shown here: https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/), GRUB was still not functional. However after reinstalling the bootloader inside Ubuntu, using grub-customizer as @PRATAP suggested, it all works fine! So GRUB is back and I can choose between Ubuntu and Windows 10.

Comment: accept your answer as it worked for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

On a UEFI system (if it came with windows 8 or later, you can bet it falls under this), the boot order may have to be changed, as installing Windows 10 will configure it to directly call Windows Boot Manager by default.

Comment: In the BIOS I have no option to choose between Ubuntu or Windows.  I will add the result from the efibootmgr to the main post.

Comment: @rinsepierins you installed Windows10 First and then Installed Ubuntu rite? Have you installed both in UEFI boot mode? if yes, Logon to Windows and then power settings and turn off Fast Boot and restart the system.

Comment: @rinsepierins if you dont success with above.. as you said you are able to logon to Ubuntu in a diffrent way, Logon to Ubuntu and install "Grub-Customizer" to edit your preferences. http://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/03/11/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu-18-04-lts/

Comment: I never had to choose between UEFI or Legacy, so I suppose it's all UEFI. I turned off Fast Boot, but still booting straight into Windows. I will try the grub-customizer.

Comment: @rinsepierins have you tried Grub-Customizer?

Comment: yeah, it all works now!!